# Need help with finding a counterexample to: if $2^h=coeq(2^{q_1}, 2^{q_2}).$ then $h=eq(q_1,q_2)$

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples, equalisers

The following question is taken from *Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative* by Arbib and Manes

Notations:  Let $2^A$ denote the $\textit{power set}$ of all subsets of $A.$  Given $f:A\rightarrow B$, define $2^f:2^b\rightarrow 2^A$ by $2^f(S)=f^{-1}(S)=\{a\in A\mid f(a)\in B\}.$  Also let $coeq(p_1,p2_)$ denote the coequalizer of the two maps $p_1,p_2$ and similarly, let $eq(q_1,q_2)$ to denote the equalizer of the two maps $q_1,q_2.$  We also define the direct image function $2^{[f]}$ to be $2^{[f]}(A)=f(A)=\{f(a)\in S\subset B\mid a\in A\}.$ We also assume the following propositions:

Proposition 1:  Every coequalizer is an epimorphism

Proposition 2:  Every onto map is a coequalizer

Proposition 3:  Every equalizer is a monomorphism

Proposition 4: The equalizer $B\xrightarrow{h}A$ of pair of maps $A\xrightarrow {(q_1,q_2)}R$ is the inclusion map $$h:\{a\mid a\in A \text{ and } q_1(a)=q_2(a)\}\rightarrow A, a\mapsto a.$$

Exercise:  Given $p_1, p_2:R\rightarrow A, h:A\rightarrow B$ prove that $h=coeq(p_1,p_2)$ iff $2^h=eq(2^{p_1}, 2^{p_2}).$  Similarly, given $q_1, q_2;A\rightarrow R, h:B\rightarrow A$ prove that $h=eq(q_1,q_2)$ iff $2^h=coeq(2^{q_1}, 2^{q_2}).$

I have a question for the second part of the question:  Given $q_1, q_2;A\rightarrow R, h:B\rightarrow A$ prove that $h=eq(q_1,q_2)$ iff $2^h=coeq(2^{q_1}, 2^{q_2}).$

I don't think both directions are true, a friend helped me with cooking up a counter example in one of the direction:  Given $q_1, q_2;A\rightarrow R, h:B\rightarrow A$ prove that if $h=eq(q_1,q_2)$, then $2^h=coeq(2^{q_1}, 2^{q_2}).$

Consider the following:  Consider $A=\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ and $R=\{0,1,2\}.$  Defome $q_1,q_2:A\rightarrow R$ as follows:

| $n$ | $q_1(n)$ | $q_2(n)$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $0$ | $0$ | $0$ |
| $1$ | $1$ | $1$ |
| $2$ | $0$ | $2$ |
| $3$ | $1$ | $0$ |
| $4$ | $0$ | $1$ |
| $5$ | $1$ | $2$ |

By proposition 4, it follows that setting $B=\{a\in A\mid q_1(a)=q_2(a)\}=\{0,1\}$ and $h:B\rightarrow A$ the inclusion map, then $h={eq}(q_1,q_2).$

Note that $2^h:2^A\rightarrow 2^B$ is defined by $2^h(P)=P\cap B,$ and since $2^{q_1},2^{q_2}:2^B\rightarrow 2^A$ is determined by the values on the singletons (since $2^{q_1}(S_1\cup S_2)=2^{q_1}(S_1)\cup 2^{q_1}(S_2))$), we note that

| $n$ | $2^{q_1}(\{n\})$ | $2^{q_2}(\{n\})$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $0$ | $\{0,2,4\}$ | $\{0,3\}$ |
| $1$ | $\{1,3,5\}$ | $\{1,4\}$ |
| $2$ | $\emptyset$ | $\{2,5\}$ |

Let $B'=\{0,1,2, *\}$ and define a function $h':2^A\rightarrow B'$ as follows

$h'(\{0,3\})=h'(\{0,2,4\})=h'(\{0,2,3,5\})=0$

$h'(\{1,4\})=h'(\{1,3,5\})=h'(\{1,2,4,5\})=1$

$h'(\{\emptyset\})=h'(\{2,5\})=2$

$h'(P)=*$ for any other $P\subset R.$

Now we check that $h'\cdot 2^{q_1}=h'\cdot 2^{q_2}$

Suppose now that $\psi:2^h\rightarrow B'$ is such that $\psi\cdot 2^h=h'.$  Then

$0=h'(\{0,2,4\})=\psi
\cdot 2^h(\{0,2,4\})=\psi(\{0\})$

$*=h'(\{0\})=\psi
\cdot 2^h(\{0\})=\psi(\{0\})$

That is, we require that $0=\psi(\{0\})=*,$ which is a contradiction.  Thus $2^h\neq{coeq}(2^{q_1},2^{q_2})$

Question:

For the converse direction:  Assume $q_1,q_2: A\rightarrow R,h:B\rightarrow A,$ and $2^h={coeq}(2^{q_1},2^{q_2},$ of $q_1\cdot h\neq q_2\cdot h$, then I need to come up with example of a function $2^h$ where it coequalizes $2^{q_1},2^{q_2}.$

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I can confirm that if $h$ is a coequaliser of $p_1,p_2$ then $2^h$ is an equaliser of $2^{p_1},2^{p_2}$. I must say, I'm struggling to show (and have my suspicions that it's false) the claim "if $2^h$ is an equaliser of $2^{p_1},2^{p_2}$ then $h$ is a coequaliser of $p_1,p_2$". Do you know whether or not this one is true?

Comment: @FShrike my friend showed me how to prove the first part:  Given $p_1, p_2:R\rightarrow A, h:A\rightarrow B$ prove that $h=coeq(p_1,p_2)$ iff $2^h=eq(2^{p_1}, 2^{p_2}).$   As for the second part, he gave me a counterexample which is this post that it is not true that:  $h=eq(q_1,q_2)$ implies $2^h=coeq(2^{q_1}, 2^{q_2}).$  For the converse, my friend struggle to give a counterexample to or to show that if we assume $2^h=coeq(2^{q_1}, 2^{q_2}),$ then $h=eq(q_1,q_2).$  By the way, the first half where my friend show me how to do it, it is a bit of a long proof.  If you want i can type it up here

Comment: It’s ok, I figured out a proof myself

Comment: @FShrike how are you able to figure it out so fast?  It took my friend awhile.  Also I am trying to figure out what Alex means [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4731087/correct-definition-of-projection-and-injection-maps-for-product-and-coproduct-fo).  I thought I have to explicitly describe the projections and injections maps.  I did not know one can prove universal property of product and coproduct for a given category without knowing what their projections and injections maps are.  That is something that always bothers me.  Because if that is the case, how is that different...

Comment: @FShrike ...different than just rewriting out the definition and consider that as proof.

Comment: Checking the universal property of maps can be done without knowing what the explicit functions are, yes. Remember in a general category the arrows are not even functions at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\p}{\mathscr{P}}\newcommand{\set}{\mathsf{Set}}\newcommand{\op}{^{\mathsf{op}}}\newcommand{\C}{\mathsf{C}}\newcommand{\D}{\mathsf{D}}\newcommand{\I}{\mathcal{I}}\newcommand{\J}{\mathcal{J}}$In all the below, we consider sets $A,B,C$ and functions $f,g:A\to B$.

1. If $h:B\to C$ is a coequaliser for $f,g$ then $2^h$ is an equaliser for $2^f,2^g$
2. If $2^h$ is an equaliser for $2^f,2^g$ then $h:B\to C$ is a coequaliser for $f,g$
3. If $h:C\to A$ is an equaliser for $f,g$ then $2^h$ is a coequaliser for $2^f,2^g$
4. If $2^h$ is a coequaliser for $2^f,2^g$ then $h:C\to A$ is an equaliser for $f,g$

$(1)$, $(2)$ and $(4)$ are correct (you are mistaken in guessing $(4)$ is wrong). You have given a satisfactory counterexample for $(3)$. Abstract nonsense proof for $(1),(2)$ incoming:

$(1)$:

> It is a good but potentially confusing exercise to verify that $\p:\set\leftrightarrows\set\op:\p\op$ is an adjunction where $\p$ denotes the power set functor, $X\mapsto 2^X$ on objects and $f\mapsto 2^f$ (in your notation). Since $\p$ is a left adjoint, it is cocontinuous. So if $h$ is a coequaliser, $\p(h)$ is a **co**equaliser in $\set\op$ of $\p(f),\p(g)$. However, by easy duality we know that this means $2^h$ is an equaliser of $2^f,2^g$ in $\set$, as desired.

In proving $(2)$ I first had a concrete proof but then I noticed it could be generalised, so here is the general theorem (this is probably well known but I don't recall seeing it before):

> Suppose $F:\C\to\D$ is a cocontinuous functor with a cocomplete domain. Suppose further that $F$ is faithful and $F$ reflects isomorphisms. Then for a diagram $\J:\I\to\C$ where $\I$ is small, an object $\varsigma\in\C$ and a family of arrows $\alpha=(\alpha_i:\J(i)\to\varsigma)_{i\in\I}$, we have that $\alpha$ is a colimiting cocone under $\J$ if and only if $F(\alpha)$ is a colimiting cocone under $F\circ\J$.

My proof:

> Because $F$ is cocontinuous, $F(\alpha)$ is a colimiting cocone if $\alpha$ is. Suppose $F(\alpha)$ is a colimiting cocone. In particular, for all arrows $k:i\to i'$ in $\I$ we have that $F(\alpha_{i'}\circ\J(k))=F(\alpha_i)$ so by faithfulness it follows $\alpha_{i'}\circ\J(k)=\alpha_i$; it follows $\alpha$ is a cocone. There exists a colimit of $\J$ in $\C$, some $\beta:\J\implies\varsigma'$. Because $\alpha$ is a cocone we know there is a unique arrow $\gamma:\varsigma'\to\varsigma$ with $\alpha_j=\gamma\circ\beta_j$ for all $j\in\I$. Note that $F(\beta)$ is also a colimit cocone under $F\circ\J$, so the equation (in loose notation) $F(\alpha)=F(\gamma)F(\beta)$ actually implies $F(\gamma)$ is an isomorphism. Thus $\gamma$ is an isomorphism; thus $\alpha$ is a colimiting cocone.

This contains both $(1)$ and $(2)$ when we consider $\C=\set,\D=\set\op,F=\p$ and $\J,\I,\alpha$ the standard ways of presenting coequalisers as colimits. I guess I leave it as an exercise to show $\p$ is faithful and reflects isomorphisms ($\p$ is *conservative*).

In light of $(1)$ and $(2)$, $2^h$ is a coequaliser iff. $2^{2^h}$ is an equaliser. So $(4)$ is equivalent to: if $2^{2^h}$ is an equaliser then $h$ is an equaliser.

You were looking for a counterexample, **but there are none**.

> Let $\eta:\mathrm{Id}_{\set}\implies T$ be the adjunction unit. Concretely, for any set $X$ we have that $\eta_X(x)$ is the principal ultrafilter on $X$ at $x$, for any $x\in X$. Assume $2^{2^h}=T(h)$ is an equaliser for $T(f),T(g)$.
>
> Firstly, we have this nice relationship (exercise): $2^f$ is injective if and only if $f$ is surjective and $2^f$ is surjective if and only if $f$ is injective. So, $T(f)$ injects iff. $f$ injects. In particular, we know $h$ must be injective. Therefore the only thing left to check is that if $\alpha:X\to A$ is a function with $f\circ\alpha=g\circ\alpha$, then $\alpha=h\circ\gamma$ for some function $\gamma:X\to C$.
>
> I know by naturality that $T(f)\circ(\eta_A\circ\alpha)=T(g)\circ(\eta_A\circ\alpha)$ hence $\eta_A\circ\alpha=T(h)\circ\beta$ for some (unique) $\beta:X\to T(C)$. This equation can be restated as:
>
> > For $x\in X$ and $K\subseteq B$, $\alpha(x)\in K$ if and only if $h^{-1}(K)\in\beta(x)$.
>
> This implies that $h^{-1}(\alpha(x))$ is nonempty for all $x\in X$, so $\alpha(X)\subseteq h(C)$. But, $h$ is injective! It follows that such a $\gamma:X\to C$ exists. It further follows that $\beta=\eta_C\circ\gamma$.
>
> Thus, $h$ is an equaliser.

Comment: I have not learned about adjunction and left and right adjoint, I am beginning to learn about functors.  This question came at the very beginning of the text where only the category of sets have only been introduced.  After I have learn the relevant concepts.  I will come back and look at your shorten proof.  The proof my friend showed me is long and not as succinct as yours due to not employing concepts of functors, adjoints and adjunction.  I can see now these concepts make things much easier.

Comment: @Seth Yeah, it allowed me to at least work out $(1)$ without needing to really think about it. It may well be the case there are short proofs for $(1),(2)$ that don't use adjunction concepts

Comment: @Seth I might also suggest again that you try Leinster's basic category theory. It seems to cover content quite a bit faster, but to a decent level, than this book "... the categorical imperative". Also my proof for $(4)$ doesn't need adjunction concepts. We can define: $$\eta_X:X\to T(X)=2^{2^X},\,x\mapsto\{K\subseteq X:x\in K\}$$And we can check $T(f)\circ\eta_X=\eta_Y\circ f$ if $f:X\to Y$ is a function. We don't need any properties of $\eta$ beyond that

Comment: I plan to look over Leinster's text after i am done Arbib and Manes.  I want to see how much of Leinster's text I can do since I think his text is more applied in the sense of having more math application.  Is kind of hard to explain in words the difference between the two texts in words.  I think Arbib and Mane are trying to present category theory with the least bit of math as much as possible as a prerequisite for reading it.