# Why is $[f(a)]=[0]$ in the proof that coequalizer is onto in category $\textbf{Vect}$

Tags: category-theory, proof-explanation

The following question is taken from *Arrows, Structures and Functors the categorical imperative* by Arbib and Manes.

$\color{Green}{Background:}$

$\textbf{(1) Proposition:}$ In the category $\textbf{Vect}$

$\textbf{(i)}$  $f$ is an epimorphism iff $f$ is onto iff $f$ is a coequalizer.

$\textbf{(2)}$  $\textbf{Proposition:}$  Every coequalizer is an epimorphism.

Proof:  If $h=\text{coeq}(p_1,p_2)$ and $k_1\circ h=k_2\circ h,$ then $$(k_1\circ k_2)\circ p_1=k_1\circ(h\circ p_2)=k_1\circ(h\circ p_2)=(k_1\circ h)\circ p_2$$ and so there is a unique morphism $\psi$ such that $k_1\circ h=\psi\circ h.$  Thus $k_1=\psi=k_2.$

$\textbf{(3)}$ $\textit{A coequalizer is an epimorphism.}$

Proof:  If $f:A\to B$ $\textit{is an epimorphism, f is onto.}$  Let $E$ be the equivalence relation $\{(b,b')\mid b-b'\in f(A)\}$ on $B.$  Following a standard if sloppy convention, we write the quotient set as $B/f(A)$ rather than $B/E.  B/E$ is easily checked to be a vector space with operations $[b]+[b']=[b+b'], \lambda\cdot[b]=[\lambda\cdot b].$

Define the two linear maps $$t:B\to B/f(A):b\mapsto [b]$$
$$u:B\to B/f(A):b\to [0].$$  Then $t\circ f$ and $u\circ f$ are both zero maps (since $[f(a)]=[0]$ for all $a$ in $A$) and so $t=u$ because $f$ is an epimorphism.  Thus for all $b\in B, [b]=[0],b\in f(A),$ and $f$ is onto.

$\color{Red}{Questions:}$

I don't understand why in the proof, why both $[f(a)]=[0]$ and $[b]=[0].$  Is it that $[f(a)]=[0]$ is an assumed fact, if so, how and why?  Hence $(b,b')\in E$ or $bEb'.$  Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it because of the following, if we let $b'=f(a)=0$ and $b=0,$ then $b-b'\in f(A),$  Hence $(b,b')\in E$ or $bEb'.$  Thank you in advance

No. You can't "let" $f(a)=0$ for a generic $a$ unless you know $f$ is the zero map. To show $[f(a)]=[0]$ in $B/f(A)$ (which, by the way, is not sloppy notation and is entirely unambiguous : )) - well, this should be easy. If not, I recommend you review how to work with quotient (vector) spaces. $[f(a)]=[0]$ **by definition** if and only if $f(a)-0\in f(A)$. So, that's if and only if $f(a)\in f(A)$, which is true. Therefore, $[f(a)]=[0]$.

*After* concluding that $t=u$, we know $[b]=0$ because $[b]=t(b)=u(b)=[0]$. That's if and only if $b-0\in f(A)$, i.e. $b\in f(A)$. And this is true for all $b$, so, it must be that $f$ is surjective (onto). So you conclude epimorphisms are onto.

Comment: oh oh thank you for explaining that.  By the way, in the [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4718253/help-with-show-that-there-is-no-structure-d-x-in-textbfmetx-such-th?noredirect=1#comment9998860_4718253) where it was confusing.  I figured it out.  Actually, a friend explained it to me.  The definitions in that post, there are only two sources for it, and the ones cited are it.  I still have to fixed some posts you commented earlier.  I will do it in the next few days.  I hope you are having a good summer.  Also, come to Canada sometime.  :)

Comment: @Seth I would very much like to. Have a good summer likewise

Comment: actually, in the proof, is it assumed that $[f(a)]=[0]$ or does that need to be shown.  If it is assumed, what allows the author to assume that?  I edited the post accordingly.

Comment: @Seth It needs to be shown but it is always true. I showed it in my post that $[b]=[0]$ iff. $b=f(a)$ for some $a$

Comment: okay okay.  Oh can I ask you about this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4687361/need-help-with-finding-a-counterexample-to-if-2h-coeq2q-1-2q-2-the).  I cannot try to find a proper counterexample. Thanks.